# Cant access MySQL online

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have spent the last 2 years writing a bit of code which is working great at home but when I try and run it at work the network policies do not allow it.
It reads and writes to the following IP: "196.30.221.209"

http://196.30.221.209/phpmyadmin

My IT guys at work can’t get it to allow
Any suggestions. (port No. etc)
Im sure you had this question before

At home and other wifi areas its perfect.

With the following code:

```
Try
    Dim PHPDB As String = "196.30.221.209"
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=" + PHPDB + ";Database=####;User ID=####;Password=####;")
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()

    Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT *   FROM TEST_DB ", con)
    con.Open()

    DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql

    DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "TEST_DB")

    DGV1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)


    con.Close()
Catch




End Try
```

Thanks a mill Guys

Comment: Ask your IT guys to unblock port 3306...

Answer (score 0):

Well I can access it so you will need to talk to your IT guys. There isn't anything we can really tell you unless you be a lot more specific in what you've tried. I'm sure your work have port 80 unblocked...

What do you see when you try and access it at work? What other details do you have? Can you access another phpmyadmin server? Have you tried reinstalling phpmyadmin?

Comment: Phpmyadmin is not needed. App with code above trying to connect directly to MySQL database.